# R package examples with external files

Tags: r, package, code-documentation

I have developed a R package with many functions that use external files as a parameter. I am documenting the package with examples and when I run the `devtools::check()` command I get an error because the execution of the examples fail. I think this is caused because I have not stored the external files where it's needed and fail trying to find these files.

I need to know how can I do to document these functions with examples and where do I have to store the external files the functions will use in examples.

Comment: You can have data files in packages, see WRE section [1.1.6 Data in packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages).

Comment: Other that pointing out external resources/documentation that explains how to do it (which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO), we can do nothing without seeing the package or at least a mwe of a package. I wonder if you're using `system.file` to locate the "external files" and/or if you have unit-tests that are looking for files.

Comment: @RuiBarradas the problem with that is that the files I need to use are PDF and, as much as I could see in the documentation, there are only three types of file allowed, and PDF is not one of those.